# euclidean distance of instances of one dataframe with all the instances of other dataframe

Tags: r

I'm working on iris data, having 5 columns what I want to do is calculate the euclidean distance of one instance of data_test with all the other instances of data_train. Like row 1 of data_test with all the instances of data_train and then row 2 of data_test with all the instances of data_train and so on, 
my data_test and data_train is split of my original data

```
library(caret)
split=0.70
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(mydata$Species, p=split, list=FALSE)
data_train <- mydata[ trainIndex,]
data_test <- mydata[-trainIndex,]
```

there is a question similar to this that proposed a solution

```
apply(data_test,1,function(data_test)apply(data_train,1,function(data_train,data_test)dist(rbind(data_train,data_test)),data_test))
```

however the problem is I have a class attribute of categorical attributes and I don't want to include that in this, I know one way is to make a subset of data_test and train and exclude my class attribute, is there a way that I can exclude the class in the line above?

Another question is that I want to find some k smallest distances from each row (data_test row with all rows of data_train) euclidean distance. so far I'm sorting them

```
df <- df[order(df , decreasing = FALSE)]
k=2
if(k>1){
  df<- head(df,k)
}
```

how can I merge this code with the above code?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: it's easier for people to help you if you provide a sample of your data, in this case, `data_test` and `data_train`.

Comment: I'm sorry if I appeared rude, this problem is just messing with my head, I will edit my post, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by "class attribute" you mean that the data set has a categorical variable that needs to be excluded from the calculations.  This is accomplished simply by indexing the data and excluding the column in question.  In addition, it is convenient to convert the data to a matrix object.

```
> data_train <- as.matrix(iris[ trainIndex, 1:4])
> data_test <- as.matrix(iris[-trainIndex, 1:4])
> dim(data_train)
[1] 105   4
> dim(data_test)
[1] 45  4
```

Now for the eucludian distances, you can do

```
> distance <- sapply(1:nrow(data_test), function(i)
+     sqrt(rowSums(sweep(data_train, 2, data_test[i, ])^2)))
> dim(distance)
[1] 105  45
```

`distance` is a 105 by 45 matrix, where the i-th column contains the
euclidean distances between the i-th row of `data_test` and each of the 105 rows of `data_train`.

Then to find the smallest k distances from each column, you can do the following

```
> k <- 3
> apply(distance, 2, function(x) sort(x)[1:k])
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]
[1,] 0.1000000 0.1414214 0.3000000 0.2828427 0.4582576 0.2000000 0.1414214
[2,] 0.1414214 0.2449490 0.3464102 0.3000000 0.5099020 0.2236068 0.1414214
[3,] 0.1414214 0.2645751 0.3605551 0.3316625 0.5656854 0.2449490 0.1732051
          [,8]     [,9]     [,10]     [,11]     [,12]     [,13]     [,14]
[1,] 0.3000000 0.244949 0.1414214 0.2236068 0.2645751 0.1414214 0.2236068
[2,] 0.3316625 0.300000 0.1732051 0.3000000 0.3162278 0.2000000 0.2449490
[3,] 0.3464102 0.300000 0.2449490 0.3162278 0.3741657 0.2000000 0.2449490
         [,15]     [,16]     [,17]     [,18]     [,19]     [,20]     [,21]
[1,] 0.1414214 0.2645751 0.3872983 0.3605551 0.4898979 0.1414214 0.1414214
[2,] 0.1732051 0.3316625 0.5099020 0.4582576 0.5196152 0.2449490 0.3162278
[3,] 0.2236068 0.4582576 0.5196152 0.6708204 0.5477226 0.4242641 0.3162278
         [,22]     [,23]     [,24]     [,25]     [,26]     [,27]     [,28]
[1,] 0.3605551 0.3316625 0.3000000 0.1414214 0.1414214 0.2000000 0.2645751
[2,] 0.4242641 0.3741657 0.3872983 0.1732051 0.2645751 0.4123106 0.5744563
[3,] 0.4690416 0.4000000 0.4358899 0.3000000 0.2828427 0.4795832 0.6082763
         [,29]     [,30]     [,31]     [,32]     [,33]     [,34]     [,35]
[1,] 0.1732051 0.2645751 0.4358899 0.2236068 0.4123106 0.5477226 0.2236068
[2,] 0.1732051 0.3162278 0.5291503 0.3741657 0.8185353 0.8944272 0.3000000
[3,] 0.2236068 0.4242641 0.5477226 0.4242641 0.8602325 1.2489996 0.3000000
         [,36]     [,37]     [,38]     [,39]     [,40]     [,41]     [,42]
[1,] 0.3162278 0.2645751 0.1732051 0.2828427 0.4582576 0.3316625 0.3162278
[2,] 0.3162278 0.7000000 0.3872983 0.3605551 0.4690416 0.3605551 0.4358899
[3,] 0.3316625 0.9695360 0.4242641 0.4242641 0.5099020 0.3741657 0.4358899
         [,43]     [,44]     [,45]
[1,] 0.2449490 0.2449490 0.2449490
[2,] 0.3464102 0.3605551 0.3000000
[3,] 0.3464102 0.4690416 0.6164414
```

Comment: I was actually looking for a way to exclude class attribute from the euclidean distance formula but this works fine as well so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out, in case anyone else wants the solution

```
library(caret)
split=0.70
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(mydata$Species, p=split, list=FALSE)
data_train <- mydata[ trainIndex,]
data_test <- mydata[-trainIndex,]
data_train <- data_train[,1:4]
data_test<-data_test[,1:4]

df<-apply(data_test,1,function(data_test)apply(data_train,1,function(data_train,data_test)dist(rbind(data_train,data_test)),data_test))
df

df <- apply(df,2,sort,decreasing=F)
df

k=2
if(k>1){
  df<- head(df[,1:2],k)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more efficient and compact to use a function like:

```
euclidian = function(
  mat1,       # Matrix with observations in COLUMNS.
  mat2=mat1   # Matrix with observations in COLUMNS.
) {
  apply(mat1, 2, function(yi) sqrt(colSums((mat2 - yi)^2)))
}
```

If you have the observations in rows instead of columns, simply transpose the matrices before function call.